# How to place a bunch of plain old Ruby objects into a models subdirectory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 3.2 app I have a bunch of plain old ruby objects in the `/app/models/` directory. I'd like to move some of these into a separate folder, say `/app/models/data_presenter/`. For one of the objects,

```
# /app/models/data_presenter.rb
class DataPresenter
  # ...
end
```

I've tried the following

```
# /app/models/data_presenter/data_presenter.rb
class DataPresenter::DataPresenter
  # ...
end
```

however, I got the `TypeError (wrong argument type Module (expected Class))` error. Any suggestions to overcome this (with or without namespaces)? Do I also need to change the corresponding models' tests names and locations?

Comment: Have you renamed all the occurencies of `DataPresenter` to `DataPresenter::DataPresenter`? It seems that some class inherits from it, but got a module `DataPresenter` instead.

Comment: When you created `/app/models/data_presenter/data_presenter.rb` did you delete `/app/models/data_presenter.rb` beforehand? Also specific call of the class/module, that raises the error, would be useful.

Comment: @BroiSats: You are absolutely right! I've had a bunch of concrete presenters which were inheriting from the DataPresenter. I forgot to proper namespacing for those...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BroiSatse pointed out, the problem was that I had a bunch of subclasses that were inheriting from the base class `DataPresenter`. For those subclasses I forgot about the namespacing, i.e.

```
# /app/models/data_presenter/color_data_presenter.rb
class ColorDataPresenter < DataPresenter
  # ...
end
```

should have been

```
# /app/models/data_presenter/color_data_presenter.rb
class DataPresenter::ColorDataPresenter < DataPresenter::DataPresenter
  # ...
end
```

or similarly

```
module DataPresenter
  class ColorDataPresenter < DataPresenter
    # ...
  end
end
```

For the tests, I couldn't find a magick solution so I just wrote

```
# /test/unit/answers_presenter/color_data_presenter_test.rb
require 'test_helper'
class ColorDataPresenterTest < ActiveSupport:TestCase
  should 'do something cool' do
    presenter = DataPresenter::ColorDataPresenter.new
    assert presenter.do_something_cool
  end
end
```